# How can I do "double-aggregation" in T-SQL / SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains Issues and SubIssues in a customer service system. The data might look like this:

| id | ticket_id | sub_ticket_id | response_time_in_mins | comment | cond1 | cond2 | cond3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | NULL | NULL | "the overall ticket about how quickly you closed down my account" | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1000 | 1 | 12 | "send ack email" | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1000 | 2 | 30 | "look up user in all DBs and remove" | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1000 | 3 | 5 | "send finished email" | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1001 | NULL | NULL | "the overall ticket about do you have my email in your sys?" | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1001 | 1 | 2 | "send ack email" | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 1001 | 2 | 10 | "look up and notify" | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I'd like to aggregate total response times for each `ticket_id` satisfying each of the conditions at a time. For example the resulting table may look like this (but assume N conditions)

| ticket_id | total_resp_time_cond_1 | total_resp_time_cond_2 | total_resp_time_cond_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 47 | 30 | 42 |
| 1001 | 10 | 10 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |  |

Here it is in *pseudo code if I could do Python+SQL*:

```
foreach ticket_number in issues_and_subissues:
  foreach condition in cond1, cond2, cond3, ... condN:
    SELECT sum(response_time) FROM issues_and_subissues isst WHERE isst.ticket_id=ticket_number AND condition=1
```

Is there a T-SQL-only way to achieve this via JOINs? or would I have to use CURSERS? any other options?

I searched on Stackoverflow and beyond and all I could find was the `CURSER` way of doing it. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to simplify the calculation for N conditions (where N is variable or a large number), you must normalize the table. I.e., there must be a 1-to-n relation between `issues_and_subissues` and a new condition table.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, that's an interesting idea. I'll try it. The conditions are WHERE clauses on the data in the same table, so I'd have to create N temp tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **conditional aggregation**. You do it by putting a `CASE` expression inside an aggregate function:

```
SELECT ticket_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cond1 = 1 THEN response_time_in_min ELSE 0 END) total_resp_time_cond_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cond2 = 1 THEN response_time_in_min ELSE 0 END) total_resp_time_cond_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cond3 = 1 THEN response_time_in_min ELSE 0 END) total_resp_time_cond_3   
FROM [table]
GROUP BY ticket_id
```

Answer (score 3):

We can sum the condition flag multiplied by the response time.  This answer assumes that the condition flags would only ever be 0 or 1.  If not, then this answer would have to change.

```sql
SELECT
    ticket_id,
    SUM(cond1 * response_time_in_min) total_resp_time_cond_1,
    SUM(cond2 * response_time_in_min) total_resp_time_cond_2,
    SUM(cond3 * response_time_in_min) total_resp_time_cond_3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ticket_id
ORDER BY ticket_id;
```

Comment: Ooh, good thought for multiplication instead of CASE for that condition.

Comment: Cool concept, but as you mentioned the condition isn't just 1 or 0, so I like the CASE method more. I think I need to augment my question a bit more, the "input table" I described, specifically cond_1,... is actually a derived from WHERE clauses on the same table `issues_and_subissues`. I'll add more context to the question, but this solution (and Joel's) might already be what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to create "conditions" out of thin air. This is usually how i do it:

```sql
SELECT
    ticket_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cond = 1 THEN response_time_in_min END) total_resp_time_cond_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cond = 2 THEN response_time_in_min END) total_resp_time_cond_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cond = 3 THEN response_time_in_min END) total_resp_time_cond_3
FROM yourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT 1 AS cond
   WHERE t.somefield = 1
   AND t.anotherfield = 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 AS cond
   WHERE t.somefield = 2
   AND t.anotherfield = 3
   SELECT 3 AS cond
   WHERE t.somefield = 3
   AND t.anotherfield = 4
 ) c
GROUP BY ticket_id
ORDER BY ticket_id;
```

Alternative:

```sql
SELECT
    ticket_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.somefield = 1
   AND t.anotherfield = 2 THEN response_time_in_min END) total_resp_time_cond_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.somefield = 2
   AND t.anotherfield = 3 THEN response_time_in_min END) total_resp_time_cond_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.somefield = 3
   AND t.anotherfield = 4 THEN response_time_in_min END) total_resp_time_cond_3
FROM yourTable t
GROUP BY ticket_id
ORDER BY ticket_id;
```

Both ways have it's pros and cons, depending on how you wanna aggregate stuff. Sometimes it's useful to create own row for each condition, in this case CROSS APPLY version can be good.